# qlabel's mouseReleaseEvent() doesn't work properly

Tags: qt, qlabel

i have a qlabel widget and i am overriding the mouseReleaseEvent() it works but not properly it only accepts mouseReleaseEvent in the half of the widget height like in the scale of 100% height it works for only like 40% what i mean is it doesn't cover entire qlabels's square(100x100) area.

THIS IS IN MAIN.CPP

```
QLabel sample(&Parent);//parent is just QWidget object
sample.resize(89,89);
sample.move( (Parent.width()/2 - sample.width()/2), (Parent.height()/2 - sample.height()/2));
sample.setStyleSheet("QLabel{background-color:red;}");

label mylabel(&Disc);
sample.setMouseTracking(TRUE);
```

THIS IS IN LABEL.CPP

```
void label::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.setText("Clicked()");
    msgBox.exec();
}
```

nothing seems too wrong but it doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: forgot to mention i also tried mouseMoveEvent(),mousePressEvent()..etc but same thing happens.doesn't take mouse input from the whole QLabel's square area.

Comment: Can you clarify the situation, please? A MWE would be better than fragments. Where is your problem, with QLabel or label? That part is not clear in code. You move the QLabel by `move()`, where is the layout part?

Answer (score 4):

Well part of the problem is that you're creating a "QLabel" instead of a "label". So of course the QLabel won't do anything in particular on mouse release. Mouse release works perfectly fine for me in a subclass:

```
#include <QtGui>

class Label : public QLabel
{
protected:
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *)
    {
        qDebug() << "released";
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    Label label;
    label.setText("Hello");

    label.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

It looks like your label (not the QLabel, but the subclass) might be shown behind something else. If that's the case, you should use a QLayout.